# Cannot run Azure Durable Function locally via Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I followed the tutorial [Visual Studio Code quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode) and created a durable function locally. I got an error message when my durable function executed await client.startNew inside the starter function

```
const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);
```

Here is the error messages:

> Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Failed,
>   Id=84dc103d-bef9-4450-b4c6-9e612c6dc263) System.Private.CoreLib:
>   Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger.
>   System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure Exception: Error: write EPROTO
>   101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827: Stack: Error: write EPROTO
>   101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
>       at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>       at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:864:14).

My environment:

- Azure Functions Core Tools (2.3.148)
- Function Runtime Version(2.0.12210.0)
- Node.js 8

Here is my code just copied from the tutorial.

```
const df = require("durable-functions");
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
        const client = df.getClient(context);
        const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);

        context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);

        return client.createCheckStatusResponse(context.bindingData.req, instanceId);
    };
```

---

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "orchestrators/{functionName}",
      "methods": ["post"]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "orchestrationClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

The problem has been fixed since npm package `durable-functions` v1.1.3

---

You have met a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/28).

> This is due to [current IWebHookProvider implementation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2024), which causes the DurableOrchestrationClient class to use the wrong webhook URLs. The workaround is to set local environment variable WEBSITE_HOSTNAME to localhost:, ex. localhost:7071

If VS Code has been opened before env setting, don't forget to restart it to bring new env variable into effect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now my function can run locally through the workaround

Comment: The github issue linked to above is now marked as resolved (as of version 1.1.3).

Answer (score 2):

Just summarized what I did in case someone struggles with the same problem.

In Windows 10

1. type the instruction in the terminal to set the environment variable

   setx  WEBSITE_HOSTNAME "localhost:7071"
2. Close vs code and restart it

Comment: On MacOS add `export WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=localhost:7071` to ~/.bashrc